# Laravel how to pass front end variable into {{route}}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

how can i pass this

```
var unit_type_id = $(this).data('id');
```

into this (replacing the 3 in `['id' => 3 ]`):

```
ajax_urls = "{{ route('unit-types.update', ['id' => 3 ]) }}";
```

in html

something like this but this doesnt work:

```
ajax_urls = "{{ route('unit-types.update', ['id' => $unit_type_id ]) }}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create url string from js and redirect.

```
  var unit_type_id = $(this).data('id');
  window.location.href = "/unit-types/"+unit_type_id+"/edit";
```

Answer (score 2):

correct concat the string from route url helper in js like this

```
var ajax_urls = "{{ route('unit-types.update') }}";
var unit_type_id = $(this).data('id');
var full_url = ajax_urls + '/' + unit_type_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this below.

```
  var unit_type_id = $(this).data('id');

  var url = "/unit-types/" + unit_type_id + "/edit";
```

Now you have the `url` as `/unit-types/3/edit`.